# PHP - IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement

```
function IsEmailRegistered($Email){
    global $con;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email FROM Users WHERE email = '" . $Email . "'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        return True;
    }else{
        return False;
    };
};
```

that's a function that checks if an email is registered before, the function returns 1 if the email is registered and returns nothing (instead of 0) if it's not registered. What I'm missing here?

Comment: Do you get an error? Have you tested your query from the command line to see if it works?

Comment: why not just `return mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0;` ? No `if` statement required.

Comment: @watcher's idea is even better - I was going to suggest a ternary, just to be a bit more explicit: `return (mysli_num_row($result) > 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;`

Comment: "*returns nothing (instead of 0)*" - why would you expect it to return `0` when your code returns `false`? How are you testing that it "returns nothing"?

Comment: It seems that You are trying to ECHO the result. In that case it really writes "1" or nothing, because that's how the TRUE and FALSE are converted to string. Try `var_dump(IsEmailRegistered('...'));` instead.

Comment: @DCoder `echo "Trying Function IsEmailRegistered($Email): " . IsEmailRegistered("smthg@smthg.com");` - it prints 1 if registered and prints nothing if not registered.

Comment: @RomanHocke that's exactly what I did - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get 1 and 0 as result, you are echoing it. Your code is probally right, you just misinterpreted it

```
echo true; // screen will say 1
echo false; // screen will say 0
var_dump($var); // this will give you the value (true) and its type (boolean)
```

---

This always returns true or false. Also **added a limit** to your query, you only need 1 hit to check it. If you need an exact amount of rows, specify it. E.g. when you want 1 row, use `LIMIT 1`. When your site grows, this will save precious resources.
Here you have your functions, optimised (IMO)

```
function IsEmailRegistered($Email){
    global $con;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email FROM Users WHERE email = '".$Email."' LIMIT 1");
    return mysqli_num_rows($result)===1; // this function will return true/false
}
```

---

If you want to stick with the if/else, you can use a ternary, the code below will do the exact same thing as your code does:

```
return mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ? true : false;
```

I changed the true/false to lowercase, always lowercase them for consistancy. You might encounter a situation where you have to send 'true' or 'false', you dont want to waste time on something that didnt work because you used a capital :)

Comment: `return mysqli_num_rows($result)` will not return a boolean value

Comment: You are correct, changed it, was making my code too short

Comment: You could use `return mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0;` instead of `return mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ? return true : false`;

Comment: The main part of my code does :) the 2nd part is just an example how he can use short if/else